# The 'CctSharedPackage' package

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, web-publishing

I have recently updated visual studio 2013 with Azure SDK 2.6 and since then I get this message and publish project is not working either. I have removed and re-installed Azure SDK and also did a re-install of VS 2013 with SP4; but the issues remains same. I have also done this...

```
gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll"

gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.dll"
```

In ActivityLog.xml i see these failures...

> > 755
> >         2015/05/16 11:40:41.496
> >         Error
> >         VisualStudio
> >         SetSite failed for package [CctSharedPackage]
> >         {77A5A151-6A9B-4D08-BC38-340AB29566E2}
> >
> > ---
> >
> > 80070002
> >         Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.Contracts.1.4,
> >     Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> >     one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> >     specified.      
> >         756
> >         2015/05/16 11:40:41.496
> >         Error
> >         VisualStudio
> >         End package load [CctSharedPackage]
> >         {77A5A151-6A9B-4D08-BC38-340AB29566E2}
> >
> > ---
> >
> > 80070002
> >         Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.CommonAzureTools.Contracts.1.4,
> >     Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> >     one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> >     specified.

The VS2013 is looking for version 1.4 of these two files while in  my 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish folder where as I have version 2.3.60417.0

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Open Add/Remove programs and find `Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2013`, double-click it and just Repair.

[Here](http://www.rajapet.com/2014/04/resolving-the-the-cctsharedpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly-error-message.html) is a blog with more details about the problem and alternate solutions. Repairing the Azure tools solved the problem for me.

Comment: It did not work; I have removed all previous versions of VS as well. The other linked issue is that I am not able to publish the application as well. It seems that I need to manually edit the config file.

Comment: Thanks enzi, the suggested solution could be for some cases. I have had to remove all versions of VS and SQL Servers and then a clean re-install of VS 2013 solved the problem; which in fact is not a solution.

Comment: Too bad the workaround didn't work for you; I feel lucky that I was able to dodge that re-install bullet :/